# I imported a DXF and now I can't add meshes?

Tags: mesh

I'm new to blender but I worked through a number of tutorials on how to build and edit meshes.

I imported a DXF that I want to use as a starting point and now the standard Shift-A menu that normally presents me with mesh options has changed to just present options for curves (shown below).

[image]

I've probably changed modes somehow, I want to switch back to whatever mode allows me to add meshes.

How can I add a mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're in edit mode where <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> opens the curve menu when you're editing a curve object. Just press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to return to object mode or select it from the dropdown.

In Blender 2.7x

[image]

In Blender 2.8

[image]

Comment: D'oh. You are right.